# how to handle the c# window service work is pending when using timer objects

Tags: c#

hi i am working on c# window services, for that i have set some timer code in onstart method as below code i have pasted it:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timerjob.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CsvGenFromDatabase);
    // ad 2: set interval to 1 minute (= 60,000 milliseconds)
    timerjob.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(DueTime);
    //  ////ad 3: enabling the timer
    timerjob.Enabled = true;
}
```

CsvGenFromDatabase is my method which will so my service, here my problem is i have set a timer (duetime) about 1 min for example if i tested simple volume job means it was performing good, if suppose if i given a huge volume of work for service to do when timer (duetime) was same 1 min at this scenario i m facing some error because still service work does not completed full but time 1 min passed away since service will poll new instance past work was not completed fully, for this scenario how do i handle to my service with out effecting any work when service was in one instance,kindly can any on give suggesions please

Comment: you need to make `CsvGenFromDatabase` reeentrancy-safe... there are difference possibilities (either ignore/disable any timer events while it is running or using a queue or just make it possible to run multiple times in parallel).

Comment: Set the AutoReset property to false and re-enable the timer at the end of CsvGenFromDatabase().  Setting Enabled to false at the beginning of the method doesn't solve the problem, threadpool threads can back up.  Be sure to catch and log exceptions, the Elapsed event swallows exceptions without a diagnostic.  System.Threading.Timer is a better timer.

Comment: @Abdul Munim thanks for understand quick, can you please suggest if you know i m new to window services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CsvGenFromDatabase` method you could call `timerjob.Stop()` before your long running process.  Once the process has complete you can call `timerjob.Start()` to start the timer again.

**Example:**

```
private void CsvGenFromDatabase()
{
    timerjob.Stop();

    //long running process

    timerjob.Start();
}
```

I'm assuming `timerjob` is available globally.

Comment: Ritche if i do like this until unless job A finished it will not start job B, hope wantedly we are stopping job B to start right ? am i right please help me out in this issue

Comment: Yes, if you do it like this, job B won't start until the long running job has completed.  Although, this does depend on how you are starting job B.

Comment: @ritche can you suggest me, in such case how do i handle for job B, i should not stop the job B until job A finish, hope you see my code how can i handle.

Comment: @pravz you will need to post examples of your code in relation to how you are starting job B?  Is this a different method from CsvGenFromDatabase?

Comment: @ritche thanks for replying, only one main method CSVGenFromDatabase under this i m using some four methods like FILEGENERATIONXXX for each message individual method, those method will jus fetch records from database based on status it will create a file in configuared path and for which we created it will update the status

Comment: @ritche you know one thing, as i am configuaring duetime as 18000 mns (three min) in app.config, hence when i start the service it was start doing work after 3 minutes, some thing timer was doing wrong

Comment: So within CsvGenFromDatabase you have multiple methods that go and do some work?  If this is the case, then my answer should give you what you want.

Comment: is my thread looks okay ? if not how to make multiple threading ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6753/discussion-between-pravz-and-kev-ritchie)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Thread to do the job, and after each invoke, call Thread.Sleep(60000) to stop the service.

here is a sample for ur consideration:

[Windows Service with Thread](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service%E2%80%94Alternative_1%3a_Use_a_Separate_Thread)

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could do is when your timer tick, in your CsvGenFromDatabase.

do

```
timer.Enabled = false;
```

this will stop the timer.

then when you are done. re-enable the timer. Do the re-enabling in a finally block.

So this will ensure your job is done before running the timer again. Kinda dirty but it should work.

Something like this
In your CsvGenFromDatabase

```
CsvGenFromDatabase()
{
   try
   {
      timer.Enabled = false;

       //do your work

    }
    finally
    {
       timer.Enabled = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please say little brief, where do i do kindly

Comment: ,after setting timer as false and where do i re-enable my timer, hope it was already there in my on start condition, is it sufficent or not ?